# Google API Gateway to Cloud Run throws 401 error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, strapi, google-cloud-run, google-api-gateway

I am new to API Gateway, I have strapi CMS deployed as container in cloud RUN and accessing the strapi API via swagger in API gateway.
Cloud run service have Allow Unathenticated for all users permission. But when I try to hit the API Gateway URL it gives me

```
{"statusCode":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Invalid token."}
```

Below is my swagger I published in API gateway. Your support is much appreciated.

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: '1.0'
  title: CMS Service
  description: CMS API Service
  contact: {}
host: www.example.com
basePath: /
securityDefinitions: {}
schemes:
  - https
consumes:
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json
x-google-backend:
  address: https://CLOUD_RUN_URL
paths:
  "/weblogin":
    get:
      description: Find all the weblogin's records
      summary: Weblogin_GET
      tags:
        - Weblogin
      operationId: Weblogin_GET
      deprecated: false
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: _limit
          in: query
          required: false
          type: integer
          format: int32
          description: Maximum number of results possible
        - name: _sort
          in: query
          required: false
          type: string
          description: Sort according to a specific field.
        - name: _start
          in: query
          required: false
          type: integer
          format: int32
          description: Skip a specific number of entries (especially useful for pagination)
        - name: '='
          in: query
          required: false
          type: string
          description: Get entries that matches exactly your input
        - name: _ne
          in: query
          required: false
          type: string
          description: Get records that are not equals to something
        - name: _lt
          in: query
          required: false
          type: string
          description: Get record that are lower than a value
        - name: _lte
          in: query
          required: false
          type: string
          description: Get records that are lower than or equal to a value
        - name: _gt
          in: query
          required: false
          type: string
          description: Get records that are greater than a value
        - name: _gte
          in: query
          required: false
          type: string
          description: Get records that are greater than  or equal a value
        - name: _contains
          in: query
          required: false
          type: string
          description: Get records that contains a value
        - name: _containss
          in: query
          required: false
          type: string
          description: Get records that contains (case sensitive) a value
        - name: _in
          in: query
          required: false
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
          description: Get records that matches any value in the array of values
        - name: _nin
          in: query
          required: false
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
          description: Get records that doesn't match any value in the array of values
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Retrieve weblogin document(s)
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/Weblogin'
          headers: {}
        '403':
          description: Forbidden
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
          headers: {}
        '404':
          description: Not found
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
          headers: {}
        default:
          description: unexpected error
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
          headers: {}
    put:
      description: Update a single weblogin record
      summary: Weblogin_PUT
      tags:
        - Weblogin
      operationId: Weblogin_PUT
      deprecated: false
      produces:
        - application/json
      consumes:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: body
          in: body
          required: true
          description: ''
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/NewWeblogin'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Retrieve weblogin document(s)
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Weblogin'
          headers: {}
        '403':
          description: Forbidden
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
          headers: {}
        '404':
          description: Not found
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
          headers: {}
        default:
          description: unexpected error
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
          headers: {}
    delete:
      description: Delete a single weblogin record
      summary: Weblogin_DELETE
      tags:
        - Weblogin
      operationId: Weblogin_DELETE
      deprecated: false
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: deletes a single weblogin based on the ID supplied
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
          headers: {}
        '403':
          description: Forbidden
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
          headers: {}
        '404':
          description: Not found
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
          headers: {}
        default:
          description: unexpected error
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
          headers: {}
definitions:
  Weblogin:
    title: Weblogin
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
      emaillabel:
        type: string
      passwordlabel:
        type: string
      remembermelabel:
        type: string
      forgotpasswordlabel:
        type: string
      noaccountlabel:
        type: string
      localizations:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/Localization4'
      locale:
        type: string
      published_at:
        type: string
        format: date-time
    required:
      - id
  NewWeblogin:
    title: NewWeblogin
    type: object
    properties:
      emaillabel:
        type: string
      passwordlabel:
        type: string
      remembermelabel:
        type: string
      forgotpasswordlabel:
        type: string
      noaccountlabel:
        type: string
      localizations:
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
      locale:
        type: string
      published_at:
        type: string
        format: date-time
      created_by:
        type: string
      updated_by:
        type: string
  Error:
    title: Error
    type: object
    properties:
      code:
        type: integer
        format: int32
      message:
        type: string
    required:
      - code
      - message
  Localization4:
    title: Localization4
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
      emaillabel:
        type: string
      passwordlabel:
        type: string
      remembermelabel:
        type: string
      forgotpasswordlabel:
        type: string
      noaccountlabel:
        type: string
      localizations:
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
      locale:
        type: string
      published_at:
        type: string
      created_by:
        type: string
      updated_by:
        type: string
    required:
      - id
tags:
  - name: Consumerregister
  - name: Mmlanding
  - name: Mmlogin
  - name: Serviceproviderregister
  - name: Weblogin
  - name: Email - Email
  - name: Upload - File
  - name: UsersPermissions - Role
  - name: UsersPermissions - User
externalDocs:
  url: 'https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/getting-started/introduction.html'
  description: Find out more
```

Comment: Is API Gateway also allow allUsers?

Comment: I don't know much about Strapi however, is it possible that you're trying to access a path that requires login credentials? Do you have any code examples of the endpoint you're trying to access? Are you calling the URL via browser or other API tools? Please add more details to your question.

Comment: Yes API Gateway supports all users, the path when accessed directly works fine, But when accessed from API Gateway it gives error. The problem i traced is, API Gateway by default append Authorization header like Authorization: Bearer null, which strapi tries to validates and throws error.